# find min value from database my sql

Tags: php, mysql

i have table like this :

```
cat_id  sub_cat_id   cat_name    price_net  promo_price  
   1         1        tshirta       25         20
   2         1        tshirtb       35
   3         1        tshirtc       45         10
```

how i can find min value from this table  `price_net` including `promo_price`

in php if i use

```
$query_net="select * from product 
            where sub_cat_id='".$sub_cat_id."' 
            order by price_net asc 
            limit 0,1";
```

it only show 25 not 10  promo_price not including as min price

in my webit's look like  :   Tshirt start from USD 10

it's similar with this question :
[Select Smallest Value From Multiple Columns with PHP/MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570881/select-smallest-value-from-multiple-columns-with-php-mysql)

hi after read other question i got what i want,
i use this

```
$query = ("SELECT LEAST(MIN(net_price),MIN(promo_price)) FROM product WHERE (net_price     != '' or promo_price!= '')and sub_cat_id=".$sub_cat_id." ");
$result=mysql_query($query);
 if (!$result) {
     die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
 }
 $num=mysql_numrows($result);
 $i=0;
 while ($i < $num) 
    {
    $pricing[$i]=mysql_result($result, $i);
     $i++;
     }
     sort($pricing);
    $lowest_price = $pricing[0]; //lowest price
    echo" $lowest_price";
 ?>
```

thank for any help case closed

Comment: what do you mean by `including promo_price` ??

Comment: i mean default price is price_net but there is discount in that table is promo_price   in the input form ex: tshirA  price : 25   promo price : 20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean this?:

UPDATED:

```
SELECT LEAST(MIN(price_net), MIN(promo_price))
FROM price_net;
```

Comment: not it's will show two min value,  price_net 25 and promo_price 10 i just wan't show only one min value from that table is 10

Comment: @CutecenzAcenz not clear what you're asking. `ORDER BY price_net ASC LIMIT 1` means `MIN(price_net)`.

Comment: @CutecenzAcenz I've added `LEAST()` function. How about this?

Comment: yes it's not clear because there is promo price if there is no promo price i can use $query_net="select * from product 
            where sub_cat_id='".$sub_cat_id."' 
            order by price_net asc 
            limit 0,1";